# Get all messages by label from gmail account

Tags: javascript, php, gmail, gmail-api

i want to create a reporting tool based on export from google gmail api.
so the main thing i want to do is to retrieve , get all inbox messages by labels from my account in gmail, and display it in custom structure in my custom ehtml document.
i want to do it with php or javascript.
I have made some researches in Google API, but couldn't understand how to start working, from where?

i think it would be nice if  could get the JSON data from this urls

[Labels](https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/labels)

[Messages](https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages)

how can i do it with javascript, what js libs i need to include, how to work with google Api? I have never worked with it before, so can anybody show me some simple full example?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a full example showing how to load the Google APIs Javascript client, load the gmail API, and call the two API methods to list labels and inbox messages. There are a lot of javascript code snippets in the Gmai lAPI docs for each API call, so you can combine the structure of the code below with whatever specific code snippet to achieve what you want.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--Add a button for the user to click to initiate auth sequence -->
    <button id="authorize-button" style="visibility: hidden">Authorize</button>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <p>Test gmail API.</p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // Enter a client ID for a web application from the Google Developer Console.
      // In your Developer Console project, add a JavaScript origin that corresponds to the domain
      // where you will be running the script.
      var clientId = 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID_HERE';

      // To enter one or more authentication scopes, refer to the documentation for the API.
      var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly';

      // Use a button to handle authentication the first time.
      function handleClientLoad() {
        window.setTimeout(checkAuth,1);
      }

      function checkAuth() {
        gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: true}, handleAuthResult);
      }

      function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
        var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize-button');
        if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
          authorizeButton.style.visibility = 'hidden';
          makeApiCall();
        } else {
          authorizeButton.style.visibility = '';
          authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
        }
      }

      function handleAuthClick(event) {
        gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: false}, handleAuthResult);
        return false;
      }

      // Load the API and make an API call.  Display the results on the screen.
      function makeApiCall() {
        gapi.client.load('gmail', 'v1', function() {
          listLabels();
          listMessages();
        });
      }

      /**
       * Get all the Labels in the authenticated user's mailbox.
       */
      function listLabels() {
        var userId = "me";
        var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.labels.list({
          'userId': userId
        });
        request.execute(function(resp) {
          var labels = resp.labels;
          var output = ("<br>Query returned " + labels.length + " labels:<br>");
          for(var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
            output += labels[i].name + "<br>";
          }
          document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += output;
        });
      }

      /**
       * Get all the message IDs in the authenticated user's inbox.
       */
      function listMessages() {
        var userId = "me";
        var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.list({
          'userId': userId
        });
        request.execute(function(resp) {
          var messages = resp.messages;
          var output = "<br>Query returned " + messages.length + " messages:<br>";
          for(var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
            output += messages[i].id + "<br>";
          }
          document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += output;
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```